# Java multiple inheritance

Tags: java

How can i make these calls , i haven t been able to find a concise answer/example.
I am tring to make root class to inherit fields from base and sub1 classes.

```
package practice;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice
{
    class base{
        void m1(){
            out.println("base class");
        }
    }
    class sub1{
        void m2(){
            out.println("sub1 class");
        }
    }
    class sub2{
        void m3(){
            out.println("sub2 class");
        }
    }
    interface gather1 {
        void m1();
    }
    interface gather2 {
        void m2();
    }
    class root implements gather1,gather2{


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Practice();

    }
    Practice(){
        root my=new root();
        my.m1();
        my.m2();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way for `root class to inherit fields from base and sub1` is to make `sub1` extend `base` (as their names imply) and `root` extend `sub1` or to make `base` extend `sub1` and `root` extend `base`.